# How to copy/download a temperory cached files to download folder in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

In my flutter application (android), successfully displayed PDF file using **flutter_pdfview**.
I am trying to copy/download the file displayed to download folder.

```
 Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
 string path = dir.path;
 File file = File(filePath);

 // copy file
 await file.copy('$path/$filename');
```

But I cant find any files locally.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path provider allows access to external storage directory as well.

For the android you can use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` method to access the Top-level storage directory.

Make sure that the Directory, returned by this method, has a path value which says something like `emulated` or `0`, something else which shows that it is the phone's storage directory, as storage path.

Then append `/Downloads` to the Directory path to read/write files from/to the Download folder.

However, this will not work for `iOS`.

Comment: Thank you, i got error no such file or directory 
path : 'storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/Download

Comment: what is the path you are getting from this method?

Comment: the path i got /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files

Comment: that should not happen... it should only be upto 'emulated/0'

Comment: let me see, give me sometime

Comment: i replace the path string after the 0 with Download. Then its work. is can i get the path without extra replace code.?
thank you

Comment: @Ajith as of now, for this library, there's no option other than replacing the path manually.

Comment: it used work a while ago, but they have updated library in compliance with Q os.   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35783

Comment: github bot has closed this topic at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35783 - `github-actions bot locked as resolved and limited conversation to collaborators on Aug 3`